# How to solve this problem with nltk regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

In the W3C Date Time Format, dates are represented like this: `2009-12-31`. Replace the `?` in the following Python code with a regular expression, in order to convert the string `'2009-12-31'` to a list of integers `[2009, 12, 31]`:

```
[int(n) for n in re.findall(?, '2009-12-31')]
```

Comment: When asking about homework (1) Be aware of your school policy: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) Ask about a specific problem with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, here is guidance on [asking homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[int(n) for n in re.findall(r'\d+', '2009-12-31')]
```

Comment: Please, don't answer homework question without explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
>>> s =  '2009-12-31'
>>> import re
>>> [int(n) for n in re.findall(r"\d+", s)]
[2009, 12, 31]
```

Comment: Please, don't answer homework question without explanations.